# Handling text overflow with a single dot at the end

Tags: html, css

If the text does not fit into a fixed-width block, the text must be truncated and include a single period.
You need to do it, preferably with css.

Tried 2 options.

First:

using text-overflow: ellipsis cut the text and added an ellipsis, then cut off the extra 2 dots using a parent block with a smaller width. The problem is that the width of the characters is different and after the ellipsis there may be an indent on the right, due to which not two points can be cut, but one or all 3.

Second:

moved the text to a new line and added a dot with after. But this turned out to be not a universal solution for the same reason. The width of the characters is different and therefore there was a lot of space between the dot and the last character before the dot or there was none at all. Aligned the text to the right edge of the block, now the point is always in the right place, but there is an indent on the left. Also in this case, the point is always added, but it is necessary only when there is an overflow.

Please let me know if anyone else has faced similar issue

```css
body { 
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 24px;
}

/*** 1 ***/

.block-1 {
  display: block;
  max-width: 125px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

.block-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 140px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #c9ecfb;  
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;  
}

/*** 2 ***/
.block-3 {
  display: block;
  max-width: 125px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #d5f3d5;
}

.block-4 {
  position: relative;  
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 140px;
  height: 24px;  
  padding-right: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
  text-align: right;

  &:after {
    content: ".";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 1px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>1</h2>
    <div class="block-1">
        <div class="block-2">Completed unsuccessfully</div>
    </div>

<div class="block-1">
  <div class="block-2">Completedunsuccessfully</div>
</div>

<h2>2</h2>
<div class="block-3">
  <div class="block-4">Completed unsuccessfully</div>
</div>

<div class="block-3">
  <div class="block-4">Completedunsuccessfully</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. The latter should be contained _directly_ inside your question, please do not just dump it on an external platform (where it might disappear from in the future, leaving the question here without proper context.)

Comment: Please add the code directly to the question - [ask]. Furthermore, whats wrong with having the ellipsis at the end? Why does it need to be one dot?

Comment: `text-overflow: <string>` used to be a thing according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow#values, but has been deprecated.

Comment: @DarkBee,  You need one dot, because the ellipsis takes up a lot of space. This is a designer requirement.

Comment: But a single dot would indicate the end of a sentence, not that the text is truncated. Seems like an UX flaw to me